# Using required bytes in a .proto file

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm scratching my head regarding how `required bytes` (should) work when serialized/deserialized via [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/).

Given a proto like this:

```
message MyMessage
{
    // 0 or more bytes
    required bytes content = 1;
}
```

I would expect some kind of different behavior compared to an `optional bytes` field. What I can tell there is no way of telling the difference between an empty byte array and a zero-length byte array on the wire.

As a side note: we are using [Protobuf-Net](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) which sometimes adds some extra sugar (like non-null `List<>` for empty/null repeated fields) but for bytes we always gets null in case of zero/null byte array, regardless of `required/optional`.

In short, what, if any, impact does `required` have on `bytes` fields? If none, is it better to always use `optional bytes` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically about Protobuf-Net, but in most Protobuf implementations each field has a `has` accessor which returns true or false to indicate whether or not a field has been *explicitly* set. You can explicitly set a bytes field to be empty. `required` just makes sure you don't forget to set it.

I actually highly recommend that you never use `required`. [It turns out required fields were a huge misfeature.](https://kentonv.github.io/capnproto/faq.html#how_do_i_make_a_field_required_like_in_protocol_buffers)

Comment: Hm, does that mean that something gets serialized saying "field set" or similar? How would the deserializer otherwise know that the field was set (regardless of implementation)?

Comment: With Protobufs, only fields which are explicitly set are sent on the wire. The protocol is a series of tag/value pairs, so the parser can tell which ones aren't there. (Cap'n Proto is very different in this recard.)